# Are "cite as" sections obligatory?

Tags: copyright

This may sound trivial at first, but if I want to cite something online or want to reference it in any other way, I sometimes find that the authors leave a "cite as" part under the content which may or may not have a certain order of fields such as "author", "title", "date" or a certain typesetting.

My question is whether I have to reproduce these patterns or whether it is enough to give the fields for example in the order "author", "date", "title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no legal obligation to do this. In general, the author is providing the relevant info in one place; order and formatting depend on the style you are using.

There are a large number of completely different referencing systems used in academia. For example, business schools typically use the Harvard style while medical schools use the APA style.

You might want to post this on academia.se

Comment: ...not to mention MLA, and Chicago book.  And those are just the major ones.